# Unable to handle two links having different pagination using decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, web-scraping, decorator

I've written a script in python using two different links `(one has pagination but the other doesn't)` to see whether my script can fetch all the next page links. It is necessary that the script must print this `No pagination found` line if there is no pagination option.

I've applied ***`@check_pagination`*** decorator to check for the existance of pagination and I want to keep this decorator within my scraper.

I've already achieved what I've described above complying the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = [
        "https://www.mobilehome.net/mobile-home-park-directory/maine/all",
        "https://www.mobilehome.net/mobile-home-park-directory/rhode-island/all"
    ]

def check_pagination(f):
  def wrapper(lead):
     if not lead.pages:
       print('No pagination found')
     return f(lead)
  return wrapper

class LinkScraper:
   def __init__(self, url):
     self.url = url
     self.home_page = requests.get(self.url).text
     self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.home_page,"lxml")
     self.pages = [item.text for item in self.soup.find('div', {'class':'pagination'}).find_all('a')][:-1]

   @check_pagination
   def __iter__(self):
     for p in self.pages:
        link = requests.get(f'{self.url}/page/{p}')
        yield link.url

for url in urls:
    d = [page for page in LinkScraper(url)]
    print(d)
```

***Now, I wish to do the same without using class and with keeping the `decorator` within my script to check the pagination but It seems I'm going somewhere wrong within the `decorator` and that is the reason it doesn't print `No pagination found` even when the link doesn't have pagination. Any help to fix this will be appreciated.***

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = [
        "https://www.mobilehome.net/mobile-home-park-directory/maine/all",
        "https://www.mobilehome.net/mobile-home-park-directory/rhode-island/all"
    ]

def check_pagination(f):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        if not f(*args,**kwargs): 
            print("No pagination found")
        return f(*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapper

def get_base(url):
    page = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"lxml")
    return [item.text for item in soup.find('div', {'class':'pagination'}).find_all('a')][:-1]

@check_pagination
def get_links(num):
    link = requests.get(f'{url}/page/{num}')
    return link.url

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for url in urls:
        links = [item for item in get_base(url)]
        for link in links:
            print(get_links(link))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply apply the decorator to `get_base`:

```
def check_pagination(f):
   def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
     result = f(*args,**kwargs)
     if not result: 
        print("No pagination found")
     return result
   return wrapper

@check_pagination  
def get_base(url):
   page = requests.get(url).text
   soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"lxml")
   return [item.text for item in soup.find('div', {'class':'pagination'}).find_all('a')][:-1]


def get_links(num):
   link = requests.get(f'{url}/page/{num}')
   return link.url

if __name__ == '__main__':
  for url in urls:
    links = [item for item in get_base(url)]
    for link in links:
        print(get_links(link))
```

Comment: You are the gem of a guy @Ajax1234. Thanks and much appreciated.

Comment: @asmitu Thanks for the comment! Please see my recent edit, it is fixed now